# Sort query_posts for Parent Pages to menue order or the count?

Tags: php, query-posts, pages, sort, order

thanks to a member here i display my Parent Pages in a 2 column grid with title and excerpt. But for some reason i can't figure out how to sort all 5 Pages by the menu order for example or the order number i assigned. 
i display them by using

query_posts( 'post_type=page&post_parent=0' );

so that the child Pages won't displayed. but i can't figure out how to order them.. Any ideas??? thanks in advance!
Dan

Answer (score 1):

Dan,

First a advice: don't use `query_posts` to get your pages. Use `get_pages` instead. Here is how you can do what you are asking using get_pages.

```
get_pages( array( 'parent' => 0, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order' ) );
```

You can also specify whether you want to sort in ascending order or in descending order. Default sorting order is ascending.

```
get_pages( array( 'parent' => 0, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );
```

For more information check [get_pages on codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages).

In case if you want to keep using query_posts, here is how you can order pages by menu order, you will need to use `orderby` argument.

```
query_posts( 'post_type=page&post_parent=0&orderby=menu_order' );
```

Comment: Thanks Hameedullah,
unfortuantely it doesn't work this way. i have tried exactly this before after reading through get_pages codex. For some reason this method only calls the same parent page where it is loaded, so that i have the same page twice on a page. all other pages (children and parents) are not being displayed, although i was sure it should work exactly this way, but it doesnt... Any ideas what that could be?

Comment: can you show your template code which is displaying the page? at least the part before get_pages. Because get_pages should return all your parent pages and you can also exclude the page on which you are displaying this list of parent pages.

Comment: Hi, this is the code how i use it now. if i change the query_post to your mentioned code it will give me only the same page again. hope that helps. thanks a lot!
<br/>
    `<div id="container2">
    <div id="content2">` 
<br/>
    `<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    query_posts(array( 'post_parent' => 6, 'post_type' => 'page'));
 
    get_template_part( 'leistungen', 'grid' );
    wp_reset_query(); ?>`

<br/>
    `</div><!-- #content2 --> 
    </div><!-- #container2 -->`

Comment: Dan, I am not sure what is caussing this strange behaviour, but I have updated my answer to include `query_posts` example to demonstrate how can you order pages based on their menu_order.

Comment: Dan, it looks like the code you posted in the comments here you're setting the `'post_parent' => 6`; is that what you want (only child pages of page 6) or all the parent pages? Then it should be `'post_parent' => 0`